# Add item(row) from a table to another table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, html-table

I have two tables. The first one contains database entries. Its last column holds a button. When I'm searching for the item in the table and I find it I will insert the quantity and I'll click the button. Then the function will copy all `td` of the row and append it in the new table.

My problem is that only the first two columns of the second table  contains the same value (`COD` and `DESC`) but `N.ITEM` should be the input `Quantity` and `DISCOUNT` should be the input `#discount` and the last `TOT` should be `[(€*Quantity)/100] * discount`.

Obviously I also need to update `Num of item` in the first table with `Num of item - Quantity`. I hope someone can help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".use-button").click(function() {
    var html = $(this).closest("tr").clone().find('td:last').remove().end().prop('outerHTML');
    $("#pdfTab").append(html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:20%;">Cod</th>
      <th style="width:30%;">Desc</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Num of item</th>
      <th style="width:10%">€</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Quantity</th>
      <th style="width:10%"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1101</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1102</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1103</td>
      <td>ccc</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1104</td>
      <td>ddd</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1201</td>
      <td>RRTT</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1301</td>
      <td>BBFF</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1901</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1651</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1231</td>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" id="discount" name="% of discount">

<table id="pdfTab" class="w3-table-all w3-small" style="width:92%;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:23px">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:20%;">COD</th>
    <th style="width:30%;">DESC</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">N.ITEM</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">DISCOUNT</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">TOT</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your description of the goal, regarding changing the values, makes very little sense.

Comment: Do not have more than one element with same `id` attribute. Currently, the `Quantity` and `addButton` are repeated throughout

Answer (score 0):

Some dirty code but it should give you an idea.

Read each column's value separately, perform your calculation then manually create a row and append it to the second table. You can add further validation of the entered amounts to check if they are valid numbers. I've defaulted the discount value to 10. Your formula seems wrong but maybe I'm just too tired to think.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".use-button").click(function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");

        //Get Values from each Column
        var code     = row.find('td')[0].textContent;
        var desc     = row.find('td')[1].textContent;
        var nItem    = parseInt(row.find('td')[2].textContent);
        var price    = parseFloat(row.find('td')[3].textContent);
        var quantity = parseInt(row.find('input')[0].value);
        var discount = parseFloat($('#discount').val());

        //Calculate your total. N.B. Your formula looks wrong but I kept it the same
        var total = ((price * quantity) / 100) * discount;

        //Update the "Num of item" column on the row you clicked
        nItem = nItem - quantity;
        row.find('td')[2].textContent = nItem;

        //Manually add each amount to the relevant column and append the row to the table
        var newRow = '<tr><td>' + code + '</td><td>' + desc + '</td><td>' + nItem + '</td><td>' + discount + '</td><td>' + total + '</td><tr>';
        $("#pdfTab").append(newRow);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:20%;">Cod</th>
      <th style="width:30%;">Desc</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Num of item</th>
      <th style="width:10%">€</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Quantity</th>
      <th style="width:10%"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1101</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1102</td>
      <td>bbb</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1103</td>
      <td>ccc</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1104</td>
      <td>ddd</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1201</td>
      <td>RRTT</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1301</td>
      <td>BBFF</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1901</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1651</td>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cod">1231</td>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="Quantity" value="0" /></td>
      <td><button id="addButton" class="use-button w3-button w3-circle w3-amber">+</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<b>Discount: </b><input type="text" id="discount" name="% of discount" value="10">

<table id="pdfTab" class="w3-table-all w3-small" style="width:92%;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:23px">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:20%;">COD</th>
    <th style="width:30%;">DESC</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">N.ITEM</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">DISCOUNT</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">TOT</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: its working good! thanks so much! yup the formula is not complete, total is the discount but we need after to do (price*quantity)-total to get the final price.. btw thanks a lot!

Comment: :) I'm glad I could help @albeert, please mark the answer as correct